# Change ActionBar Home/Up Arrow Icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I noticed that with the new Google apps, they are updating the little Home/Up icon to not be the arrow, but three little lines (at least on Android 4.2).

[image]

How are they accomplishing this?  I am not seeing an API for it in the ActionBar...

Comment: IIRC, they're using a fairly nasty hack, in advance of setting up an API for this. I seem to recall a comment to that effect from a Google I|O presentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called an [`ActionBarDrawerToggle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) and is intended to be used with the [`DrawerLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html).

You can find a sample implementation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and if you are only interested in the icons: you can download them from [here](http://developer.android.com/downloads/design/Android_Navigation_Drawer_Icon_20130516.zip).

Comment: And what if you want to then change the drawer icon to the standard up carrot icon, for example on tablets with 3 pane layots ? See Gmail on the Nexus 7, but with the drawer being able to slide in for the detail view.

Comment: Scratch that. Apparently there is a DrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(boolean) method that does just this. Awesome.