# How can i change left-point caret in ActionBar programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

The homeAsUpIndicator consists of icon and left-point caret (little arrow in the left of icon). For example, look gmail application for Android. This caret different in main Window and in the Settings window.

I know how change icon, but...

How can i change caret programmatically at any time?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16950976/2910492), which I believe answers your question. Especially the sample code that is linked (on that page search for 'caret').

Comment: @JeffreyKlardie yeh, its helpful. Tnx.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When i need to change icon of arrow, just needed to recreate `ActionBarDrawerToggle` and call `syncState()` for it.

But thought that there is method for this like `setIcon()` or any the same. Cause always recreate `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is not good solution =/

But it still doesn't work at 2.3