# Android: Locating basic drawable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawable, android-xml, android-drawable

How do you reference the `drawable` for the 'home as up' icon?

[image]

I am trying to add this `drawable` in a custom `XML layout`.  I do not want to change the icon displayed in the `ActionBar`, but rather use the `drawable` for something completely different

Tips on how to go about finding it without searching through every item are appreciated!

Comment: you want to use it as bitmap?

Comment: is this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16950907/change-actionbar-home-up-arrow-icon

Comment: Rephrased question - I am looking to use the exact `drawable` in a different location, not change it.  And as a bitmap would also be fine - I want to use it in a customview I am making

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This image is named as `ic_ab_back_holo_dark_am.png`

[image: Picture 1]

or `ic_ab_back_holo_light_am.png`

[image: Picture 2]

---

These images are at `sdk/platforms/version/data/res/drawable-versions` where version must be 11 or later.

like
 `sdk/platforms/android-19/data/res/drawable-hdpi`. You can find all images from there with there actual name.

Comment: That's the one! How did you go about finding it?

Comment: @Mr_Skid_Marks path-to-your-android-sdk-folder\platforms\android-xx\data\res

Comment: Did you just brute force look through them all? I'm wondering if theres any tricks to going through those folders

Comment: This is a drawable used in ActionBar, so you can only find it in a platform that contains ActionBar. The platform must be 11 or up.